# Python if Statement not finding value

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have constructed my own class `User` which has the property `userID`. I override the `__repr__` so that it's the `userID` string.

In another class I have an array `self.users = []` with a couple `User` instances. For testing purposes I gave them user ID's 1 and 2. I use:

```
'[%s]' % ','.join(map(str, self.users))
```

To print the contents of the array, producing:

```
[1,2]
```

I'm trying to make an if statement along the lines of:

```
if "1" in self.users:
  print "True"
```

Above is a simple representation of what I'm trying to achieve. I have tried many approaches and I can't get the program to print true. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is the value in self.users an int? cause you're checking for the string `'1'`.

Comment: He's mapping the str constructor over the list. That's not the problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you mapping `str` over the list? Normally people do that to avoid the fact that `list.__str__` calls `__repr__` on each element—but in your case, you've defined `__repr__`, and you're specifically looking for the `__repr__` value…

Comment: We're really just guessing what the elements in `self.users` are.  We know they have well defined `__str__`/`__repr__`, but that's about it.  In order to provide a better solution, you should insert a `print self.users` right before your if statement and post that result as an edit to your question

Comment: Is there a reason you need to search by string representation instead of the actual member variable? Why not just `any(user.userID == '1' for user in self.users)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want:

```
if any("1" in str(x) for x in self.users):
   print "True"
```

---

probably better is:

```
if any("1" == x.userID for x in self.users):
   print True
```

if I'm reading your post correctly.

---

Finally, depending on the API for `User`, you could use the `ID` in an equality test:

```
class User(object):
    def __eq__(self,other):
       return self.userID == other
   #other methods here
```

Now you can use `__contains__` (`in`) on your list as you were trying to do initially:

```
if "1" in self.users:
   print "True"
```

Comment: As I said to Blender, given that he's defined `__repr__` rather than `__str__`, I'd use `repr(x)` here.

Comment: @abarnert -- Maybe.  `__str__` calls `__repr__` by default though... (and I think that `str` is what should really be used here.  I would contend that OP should re-think the decision to override `__repr__` in this way)

Comment: Yes, assuming he didn't define that as well (or doesn't do so later). As Blender points out, it's probably better to change his `__repr__` to `__str__` in the first place. But either way, I think it makes sense to search for the one you made sure to define…

Answer (score 2):

`"1" in self.users` checks to see if the string `"1"` is in the list `self.users`. You're trying to check if there exists a user whose string representation is `"1"`, so you could try something like this:

```
if '1' in map(str, self.users):
    print 'True
```

Also, I'd change `__repr__` to `__str__` in your class definition.

`__repr__` usually returns a string that can be `eval()`uated back into the original object, while `__str__` returns a human-readable representation of the object. You're doing the latter, so I suggest you use `__str__` instead of `__repr__`.

I'd read through this question as well: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Given that he's defined `__repr__` rather than `__str__`, I'd use `repr` rather than `str` here.

Comment: `itertools.imap` is better here as it is more accommodating of short-cicuiting

Comment: Yes, I think that's a more reasonable fix in general. And in particular, he chose to map `str` rather than `repr` over the list, which implies that he actually wants this to be the `str` representation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem definition, it sounds like you're trying to find if you have any users whose userID attribute is '1'.

The fact that your `__repr__` function happens to use the `userID` as the representation does mean that's the best way to search for it. Why not just this?

```
if any(user.userID == '1' for user in self.users):
    print "True"
```

If you really do need to search for the string representation, of course, use the answer posted by mgilson or Blender (and figure out which of `str` and `repr` you want). But if it's not necessary, don't do it.